# Disappearing AppWidgets for Android Development

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I am developing an appwidget for android. It works fine when installing and running, but whenever the device is rebooted, the program can no longer use that widget. The activity is still selectable in the launcher, but there is no way to add the widget to the home screen without reinstalling the program.

Have you hear of this happening? How can I fix this problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: The app is not installed to SD by any chance?

Comment: no, the app is installed via Eclipse with the Android plugin.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though. Is it on SD or internal storage?

Comment: It turned out that it was indeed on the SD. When a widget is installed on the SD card, it is unpredictable when it will or will not work. As a rule, keep any application with a widget you use installed internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps installed to SD cannot have widgets. If you installed an app to SD, you first need to move it back to internal storage and then reset the phone before you can see the widget.

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) for a list of things that require installation to internal storage, and how to set up the manifest properly.